# C# Web Application with SOAP Response

Tags: c#, soap, vs-web-application-project

I'm fairly new to programming an C# and i need to create a web application project. I have been told that a website will navigate to my web application and send an ID. My web application then needs to use this ID within a SOAP request. The responce then needs to be evaluated and if it fits a criteria, the web application can load or else just throws an exception.

I can code all the application except grabbing the initial ID and setting up a SOAP request and recieve. I have all the relevant information, i just don't know how to set up the SOAP request/responce.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you working with a WCF implementation or ASMX?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a WCF, it uses SOAP by default, so if you have everything setup correctly, it will automatically serialize and deserialize for you.

```
[OperationContract]
MyResponse ParseId(MyRequest req);
```

MyResponse can hold response information
MyRequest can hold request information

Implementation could be like this:

```
public MyResponse ParseId(MyRequest req)
{
    if(req.Id == null)
    {
       //Error
    }
    else
    {

    }
 }
```

If it is really simple, you can do something like this:

```
[OperationContract]
void ParseId(int id);
```

Implementation:

```
public void ParseId(int id)
{
  if(id == null)
  {
      //throw exception;
  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

Don't forget to decorate your MyResponse class and MyRequest class with DataContract attributes.